# Action payload undefined when using axios

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

i'm learning react and i'm having issues with the action.payload object because it is not populated after doing a get request with axios.
The method which does the request looks like this:

```
const searchUsers = async text => {
        setLoading(true);

        const res = await axios.get(`https://api.github.com/search/users?q=${text}&client_id=${process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID}&client_secret=${process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET}`)

        dispatch({
            type: SEARCH_USERS,
            payload: res.data.items
        })
    }
```

The reducer:

```
export default (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SEARCH_USERS:
            return {
                ...state,
                users: action.payload,
                loading: false
            }
        case SET_LOADING:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

And the component in which i'm passing the payload:

```
const Users = () => {
    const githubContext = useContext(GithubContext);

    const {loading, users} = githubContext;

    if (loading) {
        return <Spinner/>
    } else {
        return (
            <div style={userStyle}>
                {users.map(user => (
                    <UserItem key={user.id} user={user}/>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

action.payload is undefined and i don't understand why..is it something wrong with the request? i've console.log it and it looks like the request is made successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem in your code is the use of asynchronous action creator without any middleware to handle that async action creator. If your action creator was a synchronous function, your code would have worked fine.

Asynchronous action creators need to be handled differently as compared to the synchronous ones.

There are different NPM packages that allow you to handle asynchronous action creators. One such package is [`redux-thunk`](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk). Its a middleware that allows you to create an action creator that returns a function instead of an action.

To fix the problem, [`install redux-thunk`](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#installation) and then change your action creator to return a function.

```
const searchUsers = (text) => {
   return async (dispatch) => {
        setLoading(true);

        const res = await axios.get(...);

        dispatch({
            type: SEARCH_USERS,
            payload: res.data.items
        })
    }
}
```

Some other packages that allow you to handle asynchronous action creators:

- [`redux-promise-middleware`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-promise-middleware)
- [`redux-saga`](https://redux-saga.js.org/)

Comment: i've installed redux-thunk and now it looks like it's not doing the request :( if i look over the network tab from chrome it's not doing any requests

Comment: I did
npm install redux-thunk

yarn add redux-thunk

and copied the method and is still doing nothing :(

i've also tried with
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';

// Note: this API requires redux@>=3.1.0
const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

Comment: Can you create a demo of your app in codesandbox or stackblitz and share the link?

Comment: sure, i'll do it in a few minutes